# ¿Como hacer para hacer un trigger donde despues de insertar un registro me haga un update en una tabla diferente sin que de error de tabla mutante?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-11g

El codigo que tengo es de un trigger en la que se maneja una tabla anidada de una tabla que se llama pedido, esta tabla pedido tiene un atributo que es una tabla anidada, y quiero accesar a esa tabla para actualizar una tabla distinta llamada inventario,Pero al crear el trigger me da un error de tabla mutante, que me recomienda hacer, este es mi codigo del trigger y las tablas.
 asi:

```
----creo el tipo tipo_detalle---------------
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tipo_detalle AS OBJECT(
    codigo NUMBER(1),
    cantidad NUMBER(2)
);
/
-----esta es el la declaracion de la tabla anidada del tipo_detalle---

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE detalle_anidado AS TABLE OF tipo_detalle;
/

---------esta es la tabla de pedido------------------------
CREATE TABLE pedido(
cod_bodega REFERENCES bodega,
dia NUMBER(8),
columna_detalle detalle_anidado,
PRIMARY KEY(cod_bodega,dia)
)
NESTED TABLE columna_detalle STORE AS columna_detalle_anidada
((PRIMARY KEY(NESTED_TABLE_ID,codigo)));

---esta es la tabla a la que le quiero hacer el update despues de que se 
ejecute el insert----

CREATE TABLE inventario(
cod_bodega REFERENCES bodega,
cod_producto REFERENCES producto,
existencia NUMBER(8),
PRIMARY KEY(cod_bodega,cod_producto)
);
------ trigger para insertar en inventario-----------

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triggers_de_pedido
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON pedido
COMPOUND TRIGGER
contador NUMBER(8);
fila pedido.columna_detalle%TYPE;
cod_producto_ NUMBER(1);
cantidad_ NUMBER(2);
indice NUMBER(4);
AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        SELECT columna_detalle INTO fila FROM pedido WHERE 
               cod_bodega=:NEW.cod_bodega AND dia=:NEW.dia; 
        indice:=fila.FIRST;
        WHILE indice IS NOT NULL LOOP
            cod_producto_:=fila(indice).codigo;
            cantidad_:=fila(indice).cantidad;
            UPDATE inventario SET existencia=existencia-cantidad_
            WHERE cod_bodega=:NEW.cod_bodega AND cod_producto=cod_producto_;
            indice:=fila.NEXT(indice);
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;
END triggers_de_pedido;
/
```